# Psalm 16:10: hell vs Sheol vs realm of the dead

Tags: hebrew, psalms, death, afterlife, soul

Psalm 16:10

King James Bible

> For thou wilt not leave my soul in **hell**; neither wilt thou suffer thine Holy One to see corruption.

New King James Version

> For You will not leave my soul in **Sheol**, Nor will You allow Your Holy One to see corruption.

New International Version

> because you will not abandon me to the **realm of the dead**, nor will you let your faithful one see decay.

Which is the best translation in the context of Psalm 16:10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

šᵊ'ôl / Sheol - designation for the abode of the dead. This ( thought to be subterranean) location is a *temporary* ‘holding place’ for the spirits/souls of man after man dies.

Equivalent to the New Testament ‘hadēs’ which is [unfortunately] often translated as ‘hell’. Not that the word ‘hell’ is necessarily incorrect, but rather our common understanding of what ‘hell’ is gives an incorrect ‘picture’ of Sheol/Hades. Many see ‘hell’ as the final resting place for unbelievers, where as *this* is actually meant to be ‘the lake of fire’ (Rev 20:14). ‘Hades’ (hell) is thrown into this (lake of fire) ‘in the end’.

Sheol has two separate compartments ... one held the Old Testament saints. And it was this that David was alluding to. (Sheol, colloquially known as Abraham’s bosom, Paradise - but never ‘hell’). The other was for those considered ‘unrighteous’. And the two were separated...

**LUKE 16:26** *And besides all this, between us and you there is a great gulf fixed, so that those who want to pass from here to you cannot, nor can those from there pass to us.’*

Summary - Sheol was a *temporary* location for the souls/spirits that through death [separation] of the physical body, needed a ‘location’ to go to, until (the next step)

Now, to your Q - what is the *best* translation. Well for reasons above, ‘hell’ is *not*. Sheol is the best translation because it is the most literal, but requires some understanding of Hebraic ‘thinking’. ‘Realm of the dead’ is arguably or probably the more understandable translation for most readers.

Answer (score 3):

In Hebrew **Sheol שאול** (H7585) is the "***abode of the dead***," the "underworld," and commonly translated hell, grave or "pit. The etymology of the word **Sheol** is uncertain, even the correct spelling is uncertain **שאול** or **שאל** (mostly spelled **שאול** but sometimes **שאל**).

**Hell** is the English name for the same location, in Old English **hel**, modern **hell**, of Germanic origin; related to Dutch **hel** and German **Hölle** comes from old Germanic Höhle, hole, earth hole, pit, cave Armhöhle (arm-pit), Mundhöhle (Mouth-hole).

[image]

NIV has the meaning of that place in Hebrew **Sheol שאול** (H7585) in Greek we have **Hades ᾍδης** Lit Aḯdēs (G86). Sheol, **abode of the dead** and Hades, **the underworld** are same location two different languages, therefore NIV's **the realm of the dead** is a proper translation of the word.

> because you will not abandon me to ***the realm of the dead,*** nor will you
> let your faithful one see decay. **(Psalm 16:10 - NIV)**

They have all the same meaning you also LXX **ᾅδην** (aḯdēn) Hades.

> ὅτι οὐκ ἐγκαταλείψεις τὴν ψυχήν μου εἰς **ᾅδην**
> οὐδὲ δώσεις τὸν ὅσιόν σου ἰδεῗν διαφθοράν **Psalm 16:10 (LXX 15:10)**

And the **לשאול** lai-Sheol = to Sheol, to Hell

> כי לא תעזב נפשי **לשאול** לא תתן חסידך לראות שחת **Hebrew Psalm
> 16:10**

Comment: Would the English word "Grave" not be descriptive enough of שְׁא֣וֹל Sheol? [Proverbs 15:11]

Comment: @חִידָה why you ask about Prov 15:11? Sheol has hell referering to a location which makes the word grave not fit, like Prov 15:11 Hell and destruction are before ... Or grave and destruction are before ... the grave and destruction are before .. KJV has it 50/50 31x each hell and grave and 3x pit

Comment: Simply asking if "Grave" is acceptable also as an English equivalent to Sheol.

Comment: @חִידָה Sorry English is not my mother tongue, I easily read it differently in my head then what it actually state. The etymology of Sheol is uncertain but grave fits good to its context in many of it's places. A similar word is שֹׁעַל sho-al meaning hollow hand https://www.studylight.org/lexicons/eng/hebrew/08168.html

Comment: You haven't really said much about the meaning of the Hebrew word, and you've given zero justification for saying they have the same meaning. Please [edit] this to justify what you said with quotes and references.

Comment: @curiousdannii Please be my guest and edit and add what the meaning of Sheol is! If you would have eyes to see then in the comment section I told Khadai the meaning is not fully known, be my brother in Christ and put the answer!

Comment: @curiousdannii *Sheol (שאול) is the "abode of the dead," the "underworld," and commonly translated hell, grave or "pit. The etymology of the word Sheol is uncertain, even the correct spelling is uncertain  שאול or שאל.* Crusader if you yourself do not know the etymology of Sheol, then to, dislike, to flag and demand and a answer is to make discord among a brother. 1:st is not a spirit of God 2:nd God hates the one sowing discord. Now you produce the meaning of Sheol or if you can't then do not ask for something you yourself can't do, that's to be a hypocrite. May you be judge by your own words

Comment: @curiousdannii Have you also removed my comment under Tony Chan to Austin about the difference between hell and gehenna?? That was 100% pure truth why did you remove that??

Comment: @DanielDahlberg Because it was a mini-answer, and you wrote a longer answer here. Comments on questions should just be for requesting clarification, not giving answers.

Comment: @curiousdannii you wrote "about the meaning of the Hebrew word" meaning i.e entomology I don't have that. It seems that you went on a hate spree because you removed my comment also under Tony there Austin thought hell and fire was related when i write hell is darkness and gehenna is fire. Both his statement and my answer is gone. If that comment was truth then you have removed and hidden truth i.e working against Yeshua

Comment: No, I wasn't specifically talking about etymology, synchronic definitions are fine. We expect all answers to provide supporting evidence. I'm not picking on your answer, nor did I delete your comments out of hate. If you're concerned I wasn't being fair, I've just deleted all the other comments on the question too. Please see the "When should I comment?" and "When shouldn't I comment?" sections of the [comments help page](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @curiousdannii The answer has been added! You should not have deleted the others comments but told me what I wrote wrong in the comment you deleted.

Comment: @DanielDahlberg Entomology is the study of insects. [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1012/).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda thanks I should have been etymology, to late to edit after 10-15 min. For your information Carl-Fredrik, Nyberg (Lit New-mountain) is a very Swedish name but I see you are from UK here some data over all Nyberg's in the world https://forebears.io/surnames/nyberg #1 Swe 12.902 #8 England 122. Do you know if you are from Sweden?

Comment: @DanielDahlberg I am Swedish :-)

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Glädjer mig att höra =) Har du gjort din profilbild själv? 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 2n mönster en hexagon tillåter dig att börja från 1

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of "she'ol" is controversial because of it relationship to the doctrine of anthropology and after-life experiences.  I note the following uses of the word "she'ol"

- It is the place where all people go, including the righteous, Gen 37:35, 42:38, 44:29, 31, Ps 86:13, etc
- It is possible for people, still alive to go into she'ol, ie, the grave, that is, be buried alive. Num 16:30, 33, Jonah 2:2, Isa 57:9, Ps 139:8, etc.
- The only fire associated with she'ol is that which begins on the earth's surface and consumes everything, including dead bodies under the earth, Deut 32:22
- The word she'ol is often used as a synonym and in Hebrew parallelism for "death" (ie, the grave), eg, 1 Sam 2:6, Hos 13:14 (compare 1 Cor 15:55), Amos 2:2, Hab 2:5, Isa 28:15, 38:18, Prov 27:20, etc
- More generally, it is simply the "realm of the dead" where dead bodies lie undisturbed, Eze 31:15-18, 32:17-32, and maggots rot dead bodies, Isa 14:11, etc.

Note the comment of BDB and its meaning as simply the grave, the underworld, or the realm of the dead.

The NIV never uses the word "hell" in the OT but always prefers, "realm of the dead", "the grave", or similar.  I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Is it hell, sheol, or realm of the dead? Or, could it just mean ‘the grave’? In the original language, it is שאול

It seems that there were two words in Hebrew that dealt with the place commonly known as sheol. The other Hebrew word was *'qe’ber'* (pronounced ke-boo-raw, I think). That is the word that simply meant the grave, where corpses rotted, and where there was no conscious awareness. However, the other Hebrew word 'sheol' was where the spirits of the dead went to. Qe’ber was viewed as the entrance into the realm of the dead, so it was directly connected to it, but the entrance was only where corpses were deposited and left to rot. The invisible spirit part of the deceased proceeded into the realm of the departed dead – sheol. In English, sheol is often translated as hell, but sometimes attention is not paid to this word qe’ber, when it is only the grave that is being referred to.

Many Jewish people do not believe in hell, others do (just as in Christianity some Christians believe in hell as a place of torment, and others do not). But history holds records about various ideas on the after-life in Jewish thought as in *"The Life And Times of Jesus The Messiah"* by Alfred Edersheim (1971) Appendix XIX, On Eternal Punishment, according to the Rabbis and the New Testament" (see vol. II Book V ch. vi):

> "... For the views held at the time of Christ, whatever they were,
> must have been those which the hearers of Christ entertained; and
> whatever those views, Christ did not, at least directly, contradict
> or, so far as we can infer, intend to correct them... the first
> Rabbinic utterances come to us from the time immediately before that
> of Christ, from the Schools of Shammai and Hillel. The former arranged
> all mankind into three classes: the perfectly righteous, who are
> 'immediately written and sealed to Gehenna'; and an intermediate
> class, 'who go down to Gehinnom, and moan, and come up again,'... The
> careful reader will notice that this statement implies belief in
> Eternal Punishment on the part of the School of Shammai...
> "Substantially the same, as regards Eternity of Punishment, is the
> view of the School of Hillel... In regard to sinners of Israel and of
> the Gentiles it teaches, indeed, that they are tormented in Gehenna
> for twelve months, after which their bodies and souls are burnt up and
> scattered as dust under the feet of the righteous; but it
> significantly excepts from this number certain classes of
> transgressors 'who go down to Gehinnom and are punished there to ages
> of ages.'...But since the Schools of Shammai and Hillel represented
> the theological teaching in the time of Christ and His Apostles, it
> follows that the doctrine of Eternal Punishment was that held in the
> days of our Lord, however it may afterwards have been modified... The
> doctrine of the Eternity of Punishments seems to have been held by the
> Synagogue throughout the whole first century of our era."

This is confirmed in "Josephus' Discourse to the Greeks Concerning Hades" as in *"The Works of Josephus"* translated by William Whiston, 1980, page 637:

> "Now as to Hades, wherein the souls of the righteous and unrighteous
> are detained, it is necessary to speak of it. Hades is... a
> subterraneous region... angels are appointed as guardians to [souls]
> who distribute to them temporary punishments."

Then it goes on to describe another part called "the Bosom of Abraham" with a chaos, deep and large, fixed between it and the place of darkness. Souls are in either one part, or the other, awaiting the resurrection of all men from the dead.

Thus, when we read what Jesus said about the rich man who died then found himself in hell, in torments, and to Lazarus dying and finding himself in the Bosom of Abraham, in bliss, it all makes perfect sense. Jesus was speaking to their beliefs about punishment after physical death, or to bliss in the Bosom of Abraham  (Luke 16:19-31). Jesus did not say those beliefs were wrong. He went right along with them. The Greek word for Hades links into this subject as Psalm 16:10 is also quoted in the New Testament, in Acts 2:27--"Because thou wilt not leave my soul in hell (Hades), neither wilt thou suffer thine Holy One to see corruption."   These two passages (Psalm 16:10 and Acts 2:27) demonstrate that the Old Testament term "Sheol" is equivalent to the New Testament term "Hades."

**Conclusion:** The Hebrew sheol is correctly translated as hell, and could equally correctly be given the non-literal translation, ‘realm of the dead’.  But as it is the soul  [Hebrew *nephesh]* that is being spoken of, and not the body, it cannot be translated as ‘the grave’.  Psalm 16:10 does not refer to a body corrupting in the grave. It is a soul in sheol (or, hell, or the realm of the dead).

---

http://www.ccel.org/search/fulltext/Josephus%27%20Discourse%20to%20the%20Greeks%20Concerning%20Hades
http://www.middletownbiblechurch.org/doctrine/hades.htm
https://www.gotquestions.org/sheol-hades-hell.html
http://www.apologeticspress.org/articles/2244

Comment: Dottard's answer presents some verses where it does seem to refer more to the body, for example Numbers 16:33, Isaiah 14:11.

Comment: It is worth noting that much of your description is of debates between Pharisees over what happened after death.  The Sadducees would have rejected most of this, including resurrection of the dead and the separation of those with good and evil lives after death, not going further than sheol as the realm for all.

Comment: @Henry  Yes, which is why I said "Many Jewish people do not believe in hell, others do". They were one such group. The Sadducees arose in the inter-testamental period. They were a minority, aristocratic group that became the temple party with a vested interest in the status quo, controlling the high priesthood. They rejected all religious writings except the Torah and all doctrines, such as the resurrection, not found in those 5 books. The Pharisees did believe in the resurrection and life after death.